# Automapper mapping, how to make a field not mapped

Tags: automapper

The source class has 2 attributes, the target class 3 attributes, mapping, I think in the target class has 1 attributes unchanged, I use NotMapped, but did not succeed, but NotMapped is not the way I want, what do you do?

```c-sharp
class AAA
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Remark { set; get; }
}

class AAAViewModel
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Id { set; get; }
}

protected override MapperConfiguration Configuration => new MapperConfiguration(cfg=>
{          
    cfg.CreateMap<AAA, AAAViewModel>(MemberList.Destination);
    cfg.CreateMap<AAAViewModel, AAA>(MemberList.Source);
});

[Fact]
public void test()
{
    AAA a = new AAA() { Id = "1", Name = "name1", Remark = "remark1" };
    var avm = Mapper.Map<AAAViewModel>(a);
    AAA b = new AAA() { Remark = "remakrb" };
    b = Mapper.Map<AAA>(avm);
    Assert.Equal(avm.Id, "1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is called IgnoreMap.